# click() works, hover() not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

My `hover()` is not working. When I do `click()`, it works though:

```
$( "#testcard" ).on( "hover", 'tbody #thei', 
    function() {
    console.log("in");
  }, function(){
    console.log("out");
  });
```

This would work for me, so tomc's answer worked just fine for me.

Comment: Hover doesn't work when you delegate it like that.

Comment: @TravisJ, how should I delegate then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an .on('hover'), it's just .hover

```
$('tbody #thei').hover(
    function() {
        console.log("in");
    }, function() {
        console.log("out");
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xk34xf8g/1/

If you're working with dynamic elements, you should use on.('mouseenter') and .on('mouseleave') instead.

```
$("#testcard")
    .on("mouseenter", "tbody #thei", function(event){
        console.log("in");
    })
    .on("mouseleave", "tbody #thei", function(event){
        console.log("out");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xk34xf8g/2/

Comment: Nope, didn't work. (

Comment: Wrote it incorrectly. See edited answer. Should work now!

Comment: Nope. This is where **"thei"** is: `<i id="thei" class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>`

Comment: Didn't seem to work with that version of jquery... Try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/xk34xf8g/1/

Comment: Edited the answer; All of the examples should work

Comment: second worked. Thanks @tomc!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

use above code it will solve the problem. For further knowledge about this visit this link.
[Click Here...](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp)